# WPF Multiscreen Media Application

Tags: c#, wpf

**Information**

I have a Multiscreen Application written for a Client that basically is displaying Video content with MediaElements bind to a ContentControl on 5 Screens horizontally(5 splittet Videos). Depending on wich view the User is im playing different 5 Videos and Stopping the Other Videos.

I've put the MediaElements in a library and at App Start I'm loading the 5x5 Videos with 1920x1080(mp4).
The App runs ok but I'm not happy with my Code, and I have the feeling that this could be done much better and I always keep questioning myself because of my Code.

Since I'm working alone and I don't know other Devs I would love to hear criticism about my Code because I want to learn to get better

**The Code**

```
 public class VideoWallViewModel : BindableBase {
        public VideoWallViewModel() {
            Initialize();
        }

        #region Functions

        private void Initialize() {
            _iEventAggregator = Event.EventInstance.EventAggregator;

            MediaElement0 = new MediaElement();
            MediaElement1 = new MediaElement();
            MediaElement2 = new MediaElement();
            MediaElement3 = new MediaElement();
            MediaElement4 = new MediaElement();

            MediaElement0.BeginInit();
            MediaElement1.BeginInit();
            MediaElement2.BeginInit();
            MediaElement3.BeginInit();
            MediaElement4.BeginInit();
            MediaElement0.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
            MediaElement1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
            MediaElement2.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
            MediaElement3.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
            MediaElement4.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;

            MediaElement0.Loaded += MediaElementOnLoaded;
            MediaElement1.Loaded += MediaElementOnLoaded;
            MediaElement2.Loaded += MediaElementOnLoaded;
            MediaElement3.Loaded += MediaElementOnLoaded;
            MediaElement4.Loaded += MediaElementOnLoaded;

            MediaElement0.MediaOpened += MediaElementOnMediaOpened;
            MediaElement1.MediaOpened += MediaElementOnMediaOpened;
            MediaElement2.MediaOpened += MediaElementOnMediaOpened;
            MediaElement3.MediaOpened += MediaElementOnMediaOpened;
            MediaElement4.MediaOpened += MediaElementOnMediaOpened;

            MediaElement0.MediaEnded += MediaElementOnMediaEnded;
            MediaElement1.MediaEnded += MediaElementOnMediaEnded;
            MediaElement2.MediaEnded += MediaElementOnMediaEnded;
            MediaElement3.MediaEnded += MediaElementOnMediaEnded;
            MediaElement4.MediaEnded += MediaElementOnMediaEnded;

            MediaElement0.MediaFailed += MediaElement0OnMediaFailed;
            MediaElement1.MediaFailed += MediaElement0OnMediaFailed;
            MediaElement2.MediaFailed += MediaElement0OnMediaFailed;
            MediaElement3.MediaFailed += MediaElement0OnMediaFailed;
            MediaElement4.MediaFailed += MediaElement0OnMediaFailed;

            MediaElement0.EndInit();
            MediaElement1.EndInit();
            MediaElement2.EndInit();
            MediaElement3.EndInit();
            MediaElement4.EndInit();

            MediaElement0.Volume = 0;
            MediaElement1.Volume = 0;
            MediaElement2.Volume = 0;
            MediaElement3.Volume = 0;
            MediaElement4.Volume = 0;


            OutroTimer = new DispatcherTimer{
                Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 60)
            };
            OutroTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimerOnTick;
        }

        private static void MediaElement0OnMediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs exceptionRoutedEventArgs) {
            var errorException = exceptionRoutedEventArgs.ErrorException;
            var media = exceptionRoutedEventArgs.Source as MediaElement;
            MessageBox.Show($"Screen:\n{media?.Source}\nException:\n{errorException.StackTrace}", "Media Failed",
                MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }

        private void DispatcherTimerOnTick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) {
            State = State.Stop;
            OutroTimer.Stop();
            TimerCompletedEventHandler?.Invoke();
        }

        private void ApplyState() {
            switch (State) {
                case State.Stop:
                    Stop();
                    Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    break;

                case State.Play:
                    Play();
                    Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    break;

                case State.Pause:
                    Pause();
                    Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    break;

                case State.None:
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }

        private void MediaChanged(VideoWallMedia media) {
            MediaElement0.Source = media.Video0;
            MediaElement1.Source = media.Video1;
            MediaElement2.Source = media.Video2;
            MediaElement3.Source = media.Video3;
            MediaElement4.Source = media.Video4;

            switch (State) {
                case State.Stop:
                    Stop();
                    break;

                case State.Play:
                    Play();
                    break;

                case State.Pause:
                    Pause();
                    break;

                case State.None:
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }

        private static void MediaElementOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) {
            var mediaElement = sender as MediaElement;
            mediaElement?.Stop();
        }

        private void MediaElementOnMediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) {
            var mediaElement = sender as MediaElement;
            if (StopAtLastFrame) {
                mediaElement.Position = new TimeSpan(12);
                mediaElement.Pause();

                if (!OutroTimer.IsEnabled) {
                    OutroTimer.Start();
                }

                if (!fired) {
                    _iEventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent>().Publish();
                    fired = true;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (Loop) {
                    mediaElement?.Stop();
                    mediaElement?.Play();
                }
                else {
                    State = State.Stop;
                    _iEventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent>().Publish();
                }
            }
        }

        private void MediaElementOnMediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) {
            var mediaElement = sender as MediaElement;
            if (mediaElement == null) {
                return;
            }

            _loadedMediaElements.Add(mediaElement);
            if (_loadedMediaElements.Count != 5 || State != State.Play) {
                return;
            }

            foreach (var element in _loadedMediaElements) {
                element.Play();
            }

            _loadedMediaElements = new List<MediaElement>();
        }

        private void Pause() {
            MediaElement0.Pause();
            MediaElement1.Pause();
            MediaElement2.Pause();
            MediaElement3.Pause();
            MediaElement4.Pause();
        }

        private void Play() {
            MediaElement0.Play();
            MediaElement1.Play();
            MediaElement2.Play();
            MediaElement3.Play();
            MediaElement4.Play();
        }

        private void Stop() {
            MediaElement0.Stop();
            MediaElement1.Stop();
            MediaElement2.Stop();
            MediaElement3.Stop();
            MediaElement4.Stop();
        }

        #endregion
```

Comment: Do you really want to play all media elements at the same time?

Comment: yes this are basically 5 screens with one whole video splitet on 5 screens so 5 videos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A way to reduce the amount of code in initialize and allow it to be more flexible is by putting your `MediaElements` into an array:

```
var mediaElems = new[]{
    new MediaElement(),
    new MediaElement(),
    new MediaElement(),
    new MediaElement(),
    new MediaElement()
}

foreach(var elem in mediaElems){
    elem.BeginInit();
    elem.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
    elem.Loaded += MediaElementOnLoaded;
    elem.MediaOpened += MediaElementOnMediaOpened;
    elem.MediaEnded += MediaElementOnMediaEnded;
    elem.MediaFailed += MediaElement0OnMediaFailed;
    elem.EndInit();
    elem.Volume = 0;
}
```

If you let this be a field of your class `this._mediaElems` you can also reduce `Pause`, `Play` and `Stop`

```
private void Pause() {
    foreach(var elem in _mediaElems){
        elem.Pause();
    }
}

private void Play() {
    foreach(var elem in _mediaElems){
        elem.Play();
    }
}

private void Stop() {
    foreach(var elem in _mediaElems){
        elem.Stop();
    }
}
```

You defined `ApplyState` but you forgot to use it on `MediaChanged`. 
You should apply the same array idea to `VideoWallMedia`, however I would first start by looking at `VideoWallMedia` and `MediaElement` and see how they are related, it seems they are not modeled correctly.

This method is not being referenced anywhere, maybe you can delete the code?

```
private void MediaChanged(VideoWallMedia media) {
    _mediaElems[0].Source = media.Video0;
    _mediaElems[1].Source = media.Video1;
    _mediaElems[2].Source = media.Video2;
    _mediaElems[3].Source = media.Video3;
    _mediaElems[4].Source = media.Video4;

    ApplyState();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Nice Review. I cant put those MediaElements in an Array because im binding them to a ContentControl.  Or would this be possible?

Comment: @iNCEPTiON_ If I am not mistaken there's nothing stopping you from putting them into an array even if you use binding.